# geom_tile() in R: Sort Order

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I have a dataframe that I want to plot a heatmap of:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(`0` = c(6.08, 7.91, 5.14, 2.23, 0.72, 0.19, 0.04, 
0.01, 0, 0, 0), `1` = c(9.12, 11.86, 7.71, 3.34, 1.09, 0.28, 
0.06, 0.01, 0, 0, 0), `2` = c(6.84, 8.89, 5.78, 2.5, 0.81, 0.21, 
0.05, 0.01, 0, 0, 0), `3` = c(3.42, 4.45, 2.89, 1.25, 0.41, 0.11, 
0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0), `4` = c(1.28, 1.67, 1.08, 0.47, 0.15, 0.04, 
0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0), `5` = c(0.38, 0.5, 0.33, 0.14, 0.05, 0.01, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `6` = c(0.1, 0.13, 0.08, 0.04, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), `7` = c(0.02, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), `8` = c(0, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `9` = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `10 or more` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10 or more"), class = "data.frame")
```

Now to plot the heatmap using ggplot2 this is how I approach the solution:

```
df %>% 
as_tibble(rownames = "homeScore") %>%
pivot_longer(cols = -homeScore, names_to = "awayScore", values_to = "level") %>%
ggplot() +geom_tile(aes(x=homeScore, y=awayScore, fill = level))
```

The problem I face is that the columns and rows are being sorted on (0,1,10+,2,..) instead of (0,1,2,...10+). Here's the example:

[image]

How do I sort the values such that 10+ is the last for row and column, instead of the third?

Comment: do the old `as.numeric() %>% as.factor()` razzle dazzle on `level`, b/c right now it is a `character` that just looks like numbers

Comment: `+geom_tile(aes(x=homeScore, y=awayScore, fill = as.factor(as.numeric(level)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Nate already mentioned you have to convert your vars to factors and put the levels in the right order. Instead of converting via `factor(as.numeric(.))` (which converts "10 or more" to `NA`) I would recommend to make use of `forcats::fct_relevel` which allows you to change the order of the levels, e.g. `forcats::fct_relevel(homeScore, "10 or more", after = 10)` will change the order of the levels such that `10 or more` becomes the last level. Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df %>% 
  as_tibble(rownames = "homeScore") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -homeScore, names_to = "awayScore", values_to = "level") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(homeScore, awayScore), ~forcats::fct_relevel(.x, "10 or more", after = 10)) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_tile(aes(x=homeScore, y=awayScore, fill = level))
```

[image]